# ExcelVba Goal Seek for dynamic goal

Tags: excel, vba

I set up a goal seek using macro to calculate break even of selling price by setting target profit as $1000. I am now wondering if i can change my vba coding in a way that if i change  Set target profit (Goal value) from 1000 to say 200 (or any number), it will update break even price.

Set Cell  E12 
Changing Cell B5
to value is 1000 c12 (Which i am entering manually in goal seek tab)

```
Sub FindBreakEven()
'
' FindBreakEven Macro
'

    Range("E12").GoalSeek Goal:=1000, ChangingCell:=Range("B5")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you set a cell to your Goal value, then in your code put `Goal:=Range("A1").Value` or something like that?

Comment: Yes i tried that and it is working. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub FindBreakEven()
'
' FindBreakEven Macro
'

    Range("E12").GoalSeek Goal:=Range("B6"), ChangingCell:=Range("B5")
End Sub
```